# How do you prepare Brie?

Tags: cheese, cheese-making

My son enjoys the Brie that comes with the cheese plate at Starbucks.  That cheese has a mild aroma.  So I picked up some Brie from the market and it has a strong smell.  Is there a way to prepare Brie to reduce the odor?  Or if I knew anything about cheese would I even try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ammonia odor means over-ripe cheese](http://www.thenibble.com/reviews/main/cheese/cheese2/whey/brie-camembert.asp). For both Camembert and Brie.

Next time don't buy it ...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The riper the brie is, the stronger the flavour is.

Therefore I would recommend choosing a hard brie and then allow it to ripen (unless you want it really not strong)...Also you should experiment with different types of brie as some are stronger than others.

I tend to find that french brie is stronger than English...

Enjoy your cheese experimenting!

Fi